# How to solve the following combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is Joyce must determine how many marbles are in a box to win a math contest. She is told that there are 3 identical red marbles and some number of identical white marbles in the box. She is also told that there are 35 linear permutations of marbles. What number should Joyce Choose?

I didn't know what linear permutation meant so I googled it and it says linear arrangements of objects in order. What I got from the question was there are total 35 marbles, so to find the answer i just added $$35+3$$ which I know is totally wrong because it can't be that easy, I don't even think I understand what the question is asking. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Hint: If there were $2$ white marbles and $5$ marbles in total then (try it) the number of visually distinct linear arrangements would be $\displaystyle {5 \choose 3}=\frac{5!}{3!\,2!}=10 \not = 35$.  So the answer is not $5$

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: so how can i solve it

Comment: @MathAsker The count of arrangements of $3$ red and $n-3$ white marbles is $\dfrac{n!}{3!~(n-3)!}$. $~$ Having been told that this is $35$, find the value of $n$ which makes it so. $~$ (PS: the factorial is defined as $0!=1$ and for all integer $x$ as $~x! = x\cdot (x-1)\cdot (x-2)\cdots 2\cdot 1~$ for all integer $x\geq 1~$)

Answer (score 1):

There are $35$ linear permutations of $3$ red and $n-3$ white marbles.

$$\begin{align}35 ~=~& \dfrac{n!}{3!~(n-3)!} \\[1ex] 3!\cdot 35 =~& n(n-1)(n-2) \end{align} $$

Solve this for $n$.

> Big Hint: what are the factors of $35$?

Comment: This seems fine. A downvote without explanation is strange, and perhaps misleading to others; (+1) to undo.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

I think @Henry's Comment should have been enough; and then @GrahamKemp's
helpful explanation added to that. Maybe you don't understand
the idea of solving ${n \choose 3} = 35$ for $n.$ So here is a chance to think a
little more deeply.

In a row of $n$ positions, there are 35 distinguishable ways to select three positions for the red marbles.

```
 RRRWWW...,  RRWRWW...,  RWWRRW..., RwRwRW..., and so on.
```

Pretty much obviously, $n = 1$ is impossibly small and $n = 100$ is way too large.  Why?

The R procedure below is sometimes called a 'grid search'. 
(In English: "Have the computer try every reasonable value and pick the one that works.")

```
n = 1:100    # n is a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive)
perm = choose(n, 3)  # distinguishable arrangements
n[perm==35]  # n such that the number of distinguishable arrangements is 35
## 7
```